# Selenium/Xvfb Issues with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, xvfb, selenium

I'm struggling to get Jenkins to run Selenium/Xvfb for some functional tests on a project. Either Jenkins will hang and the job never finishes or ends up terminating with errors. This is using the Xvfb plugin. Here's one of the most recent tracebacks--

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_update_yeast_invalid_form_validation (functional_tests.test_simple_yeast_validation_form.YeastFormValidation)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProj/functional_tests/base.py", line 29, in setUp
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/d4d78946/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 158, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/d4d78946/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/d4d78946/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/d4d78946/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/d4d78946/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 25 tests in 33.513s

FAILED (errors=19, skipped=6)
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Build step 'Virtualenv Builder' marked build as failure
Xvfb stopping
unlink: No such file or directory
unlink /var/lib/jenkins/xvfb-30-..fbdir854052494809466199/Xvfb_screen0 failed, Invalid argumentFinished: FAILURE
```

This may be related to an issue where Xvfb is running even though I terminated the job. Here are my settings:

Start Xvfb before the build, and shut it down after = checked
Xvfb specific display name = 99
Timeout in seconds = 10
Xvfb display name offset = 0
Log Xvfb output = checked

I tried using the inject environment variables plugin to add the following env var--
DISPLAY=:99.0

I tried searching for logs but wasn't able to find anything on Google for a log location. Could anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is related, to issue, so I'm just throwing this out there:  when a job finishes, Jenkins forcibly terminates any processes that were started during that job.  This applies even to processes that have been disowned from their parent.  It sounds like you may be starting some background/daemon processes as part of your job, so this may be the reason. See: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Comment: This is a pretty bare bones Centos 7 VM. I'm only using it for Jenkins processes. The only other thing I can think of is that I have Elasticsearch running on the machine. Would that possible have an affect? My unit tests run just fine, just not Selenium/Xvfb